# In R, how to generate a dataset consisting of the means of all column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataset, simulation, distribution, replicate

I can generate 20 observations of a uniform distribution with the runif function :  `runif(n=20)`
and 100 replicates of the same distribution as following.

```
df <- replicate( 100, runif(n=20))
```

This creates `df` a matrix of dimensions `[20,100]` which I can convert into a data frame with 100 columns and 20 rows.

How can I generate a new data frame consisting of the means of each column of `df` ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: minor point: in R, they're functions, not commands!

Answer (score 11):

You can use `colMeans`.

```
data <- replicate(100, runif(n=20))
means <- colMeans(data)
```

Comment: R 2.15+ also includes `.colMeans()`. According to the note, these are "for use in programming where ultimate speed is required."

Answer (score 5):

#### Generate data:

```
data <- replicate(100, runif(n=20))
```

#### Means of columns, rows:

```
col_mean <- apply(data, 2, mean)
row_mean <- apply(data, 1, mean)
```

#### Standard deviation of columns, rows

```
col_sd   <- apply(data, 2, sd)
row_sd   <- apply(data, 1, sd)
```

Comment: `colMeans`, `rowMeans`, `colSums`, and `rowSums` will generally perform faster than their `apply` equivalents, though for *most* cases, the performance hit will not be a huge deal (obviously depends on the size of your data...).

Comment: check out the help page for `?colMeans` for details, but essentially those functions are "written for speed" and do less error checking than the `apply` functions. I wish I understood the details better myself...

Comment: On a 10000 x 10000 matrix `colMeans` took ~0.1s, `apply` ~3.2s.

Answer (score 2):

if i understand correctly:

`apply(replicate(100,runif(n=20)),2,mean)`

Comment: Dear frankc: Thank you very much for your help- I tried your suggestion and it indeed worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of Nico's answer, you could instead make one call to `runif()`, format it into a matrix, and then take the colMeans of that. It proves faster and is equivalent to the other answers.

```
library(rbenchmark)
#reasonably fast
f1 <- function() colMeans(replicate(100,runif(20)))
#faster yet
f2 <- function() colMeans(matrix(runif(20*100), ncol = 100))

benchmark(f1(), f2(), 
          order = "elapsed", 
          columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"),
          replications=10000)

#Test results
  test elapsed relative
2 f2()    0.91 1.000000
1 f1()    5.10 5.604396
```